# Каким образом лучше реализовать замену букв на цифры в SQL

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

Есть такой код на C#. Как лучше реализовать тоже-самое в SQL для MS SQL SERVER?

```
public static string CharToNumbers(string inputStr)
    {
        Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int> 
        { 
            {'A', 10}, {'B', 11}, {'C', 12}, {'D', 13},
            {'E', 14}, {'F', 15}, {'G', 16}, {'H', 17},
            {'I', 18}, {'J', 19}, {'K', 20}, {'L', 21},
            {'M', 22}, {'N', 23}, {'O', 24}, {'P', 25},
            {'Q', 26}, {'R', 27}, {'S', 28}, {'T', 29},
            {'U', 30}, {'V', 31}, {'W', 32}, {'X', 33},
            {'Y', 34}, {'Z', 35}
            };

        for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.Length; i++)
        {
            int val = 0;
            if (dict.TryGetValue(inputStr[i], out val))
                inputStr = inputStr.Replace(inputStr[i].ToString(), val.ToString());
        }
        return inputStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Или Вы можете использовать *recursive query*.

для *SQL Server*:

```
with tmp as (
    select 1 as id
    union all
    select tmp.id+1
    from tmp
    where tmp.id < 26
    )
    select id, char(id + 64) character from tmp;
```

Для *Oracle*:

```
select
  chr(level + 64) character,
  level + 10 id
from dual connect by level <= 26;
```

Comment: А как это мне прикрутить теперь для SQL Server? Допустим в таблице BANK есть столбец SCH_IK в котором нужно произвести замену. Как мне применить это для этого столбца?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CharToNumbers( P_STR IN VARCHAR2)
IS
V_STR VARCHAR2(2*LENGTH(P_STR));
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1..LENGTH(P_STR)
LOOP
   V_STR := V_STR || 
   CASE SUBSTR(P_STR, I, 1) WHEN 'A' THEN '10' WHEN 'B' THEN '11' ELSE '?' END
END LOOP;
RETURN V_STR;
END;
```

Comment: А как это будет выглядеть для MS SQL SERVER?